# "mvn test" gives different errors in console

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have been facing these three errors:

1. Users.java:[8,40] error: cannot find symbol
2. Users.java:[5,25] error: package com.project.tests does not exist
3. listeners class not found.

I went to these lines and found that **line 8,40** has this error because it couldn't found the variable(symbol)at this line.For 2nd error I went to the line and it is `import com.project.tests.Repo;`.

There are two packages `import com.project.tests` in source folder `src/test/java` and `import com.project.live` in `src/main/java`. So it is able to find `import com.project.live` but not the `import com.project.tests` and `com.project.tests.Repo;` lies in package `import com.project.tests`, and that's why it is giving error.

On reading different posts on stackoverflow.com and on other forums, I found that first two errors can be fixed by updating `maven-compiler-plugin` to `version 3.1` and updating `testng` to latest. Yesterday I made both the changes and tested, so both errors were removed and it started giving #3 error.
But today when I do `mvn test`, followed by `mvn clean`, it sometimes gives errors 1 and 2 together and sometimes error 3 alone.
I don't understand what's happening. To get rid of this I deleted `.m2` and get it again using `mvn install` but no change, it kept on behaving weird.
I have pasted `pom.xml` below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>project</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resource</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>send a mail</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>send-mail</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <from>
                                myofficial@emailid.com
                            </from>
                            <subject>
                                Test Results
                            </subject>
                            <failonerror>
                                true
                            </failonerror>
                            <mailhost>
                            </mailhost>
                            <receivers>
                                <receiver>myofficial2@emailid.com</receiver>
                            </receivers>
                            <htmlMessageFile>
                                /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Testing/workspace/target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html
                            </htmlMessageFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven suerfire config -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>
                            /home/ubuntu/automation/projectAutomate/Chrome.xml
                        </suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testFailureIgnore>
                        true
                    </testFailureIgnore>

                    <properties>

                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>
                                org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,
                                org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter
                            </value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>



            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <!-- TestNG-xslt related configuration. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.testng.xslt</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng-xslt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Output directory for the report -->
                    <outputDir>
                        /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DailySignUpTests/workspace/target/testng-xslt-report/
                    </outputDir>
                    <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
                    <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testDetailsFilter>
                    <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>
                                org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,
                                org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter
                            </value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>
            UTF-8
        </project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- first -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.34.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.34.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.34.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.34.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hudsonci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.32-h-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- second -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- third -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
org.slf4j
          </groupId>
            <artifactId>
nlog4j
          </artifactId>
            <version>
1.2.25
          </version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java-net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: You seem to have a compilation problem (errors #1, #2), you should show us the `Users.java` source code to help you better. Concerning #3, given the provided info, I find it hard to help you (what is listener ? + show us some Java code ...). You shouldn't need to delete .m2 to fix your maven problems : `mvn -U` should be enough

Comment: 1. `mvn -U` not working (what this command does?) 2. You mean I should look for error in `User.java` at lines 40 and 25 ?

Comment: 1. `-U` must be used with another command (ex: `mvn package -U`). The `-U` or `--update-snapshots` options forces to refresh snapshot dependencies and missing release dependencies. 2. Yes you should look for errors in Java source (`User.java`). That is actually what the compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual cause for this is that you're using test classes in code below `src/main/java/`. Maven doesn't allow this - for good reason. Keep all your test code under `src/test/java`.

Also make sure all Java code is in `src/*/java`; the files in `src/*/resources` are not considered code my Maven.

Comment: I have moved all `java` files with `@Test` annotations i.e.test classes which I want to execute using `Chrome.xml`(as shown in my `pom.xml` above), to `src/test/java` and reusable classes those methods are called in classes having `@Test` annotations, to `src/main/java`. But it is still not helping. And for second suggestion should I write `<directory>src/*/java</directory>` under `<testResource>` tag.